# Is there a python libary that lets you call a function inside a function wtihout creating a recursive stack

Tags: python, transition, fsm

I am trying to switch from one state to another state. Each state is represented by a function. I would like to handle the logic of switching inside the function instead of a main loop that calls on the function. Is there a python library that allow that kind of pattern. 
So for example:

```
def c(count):
    if count<10:
        a(count+1)
        print("dont' keep track of post-order printing")
    else:
        print("when count is reached, program should terminate")
def b(count):
    c(count):
def a(count):
    b(count)
a()
```

This is just an example, I am trying to use a finite state pattern where the logic is inside the transition on_enter methods. Basically, the machine will automatically transition from one state to the next, without the use of a main_loop.

Comment: i'd probably look at coroutines for this

Comment: @user252046 what is the problem with recursive. why do you want "without it"?

Comment: I don't want the program to call back after reaching the base case. And the loop goes on forever. I know it can be accomplished by having a main loop that calls on the functions, but it would create a whole lot of mess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[transitions](https://github.com/pytransitions/transitions) features ordered transitions as well as `queued` transitions which might be what you are looking for. The basic trick is to call the same event whenever the very same event has been processed (with `finalize`). Callbacks passed to `finalize` will processed even if the transition has not been successful (not all `conditions` returned `True`). With `queued` transitions will not process the event right away but right after the currently processed event which will prevent massive recursion.

```
from transitions import Machine
import time


class Model(object):

    # initialise counter and counter limit
    def __init__(self):
        self.counter = 0
        self.limit = 5

    # will be called in every cycle and increase the counter
    def increase_counter(self):
        self.counter += 1
        print("Counter increased to ", self.counter)
        time.sleep(0.5)

    # will be called whenever a new state has been entered
    def reset_counter(self):
        self.counter = 0
        print("Counter reset; Current state is ", model.state)

    # this function returns whether the limit has already been reached
    def limit_reached(self):
        return self.counter >= self.limit

# initialising the previously defined model
model = Model()
# creating some state names
states = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']

# configuring the state machine:
# pass the model (for callbacks), pass the state names,
# disable auto_transitions since we will not need them
# set the initial state to 'A' and call a (currently) undefined
# model function 'next_state' after EVERY triggered event.
# 'queued' means that every transition is finished before the next event is handled
machine = Machine(model, states=states, auto_transitions=False,
                  queued=True, initial='A', finalize_event='next_state')

# now add ordered transitions: 
# Depending on the order of the passed state names,
# create transitions from each state 'n' to state 'n+1' called 'next_state'.
# 'prepare' each transition attempt by increasing the counter
# afterwards check the 'conditions' (is the counter limit reached)
# if all callbacks in 'conditions' return True, the transition
# is conducted and callbacks in 'after' are processed (counter reset)
machine.add_ordered_transitions(prepare='increase_counter', conditions='limit_reached',
                                after='reset_counter', trigger='next_state')

# model will go into an infinite loop; can be triggered in a thread
model.next_state()
```

You can try to reduce the sleep timer in `increase_counter` to check whether you will hit a recursion error (you shouldn't). If you set `queued=False` which is the standard behaviour, you will hit the recursion error more or less right away since all machine triggers will be processed instantly.

Answer (score 1):

There is fn.tcor https://github.com/kachayev/fn.py/blob/master/README.rst#trampolines-decorator. But the library seems to be unmaintained.. You may look for tail optimization in Python... You may find something..

Answer (score 0):

I hope it may it may suits your expectation

```
def c(count):
    if count<10:
        print("don't keep track of post-order printing")
        c(count+1)
    else:
        print("when count is reached, program should terminate")
```

Output:

```
>>> c(1)
don't keep track of post-order printing
don't keep track of post-order printing
don't keep track of post-order printing
don't keep track of post-order printing
don't keep track of post-order printing
don't keep track of post-order printing
don't keep track of post-order printing
don't keep track of post-order printing
don't keep track of post-order printing
when count is reached, program should terminate
```